# Using if then statements R to changing existing values of variable

Tags: r, if-statement, syntax

I have a data frame with a variable AGE_YR. I want to convert any ages less than 1 to 1.

I am unsure how to write this using an if then/else statement in R and seem to be stuck on using my SAS knowledge which is obviously not helping.

Logically I want to write something like this `If df$AGE_YR < 1 THEN df$AGE_YR == 1` but the syntax is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not far off

```
df$AGE_YR <- ifelse(df$AGE_YR < 1, 1, df$AGE_YR)
```

Might yield better run time

```
df$AGE_YR <- pmax(df$AGE_YR, 1)
```

Comment: Hi @Sweepy Dodo, this is super helpful but just so I understand how this reads, is this telling R that "if I AGE_YR is less than 1, the resulting output should be 1 for AGE_YR"?

Comment: u are half way there. If AGE_YR < 1, then 1. Else, AGE_YR

Comment: np. Had to delete the 2nd solution i.e. `max(df$AGE_YR, 1)` as it was not apt for purpose